# Unable to execute if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I feel like this may be an easy solution but I am having a hard time understanding on why I unable to get rid of the errors in regards to my if statement.

I am getting a number of syntax errors in regards to my if statement 

          `if (selectedDate < new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]) {
        selectableRows: "none"
        }`

I've tried adding a return (selectableRows: "none") but that did not resolve my issues either.

```
 const custom = {
        customToolbar: () => <DataTableRefreshButton refresh={refresh} />,
        customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows, displayData) => (
            <TestToolBar
                data={data}
                alert={alert}
                rows={rows}
                type={type}
            />
        ),
        isRowSelectable: (displayData) => {

            const data= updatedStaff[
                data
            ];
         return (currentData.ActionTypeID > 0 || currentData.ActionCompletedByID > 0   ? false : true)
        },
         if (selectedDate < new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]) {
        selectableRows: "none"
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplifying, you have a structure like this:

```
const custom = {
    firstProperty: 1,
    secondProperty: 'test',
    if (someCondition) {
        thirdProperty: 'third'
    }
};
```

This is not valid JavaScript.  You can use `if` blocks when writing multiple statements, but not in the middle of setting the properties of an object.

If there's a valid default for that property, you can use the ternary conditional operator to set it:

```
const custom = {
    customToolbar: ...
    customToolbarSelect: ...
    isRowSelectable: ...
    selectableRows: (selectedDate < new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0]) ? 'none' : 'default'
}
```

Otherwise you may need to more dynamically build your object.  Something like:

```
const custom =
    (selectedDate < new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0])
    ? { /* properties with selectableRows */ }
    : { /* properties without selectableRows */ }
```